# Bootstrap navbar style change on toggle

Tags: css, wordpress, toggle

I am using a WP theme(bootstrap). When resize my window to mobile view, i see a button of toggle menu (3 horizontal lines). On clicking it, i see a drop down type list of pages.

I want to change that drop down to open like right to left. 
Just like this : [Here is the link](http://html5up.net/spectral)

How to change the dropping style from [top To Bottom] to [Right To Left]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to look at Bootstrap's 'off-canvas' menu. Unfortunately it's not just a simple change from top to bottom to right and left but it's quite straight forward to achieve using this demo example.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/